# Aravot for Hoshannah Rabbah in place of ordinary ones?

Tags: sukkot, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, hoshana-rabbah

By Hoshannah Rabbah, my aravot invariably get rather unattractive. Furthermore, it becomes somewhat difficult to do hoshanot while holding the lulav, etrog, and excess aravot used on H"R. Is it an accepted practice to attach these aravot to the lulav instead of/in addition to the regular aravot?

Comment: [Succah 44b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=7&daf=44b&format=pdf)

Answer (score 1):

See Kitzur Shulchan Aruch [סימן קלח - דיני הושענא רבא](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0136_L2)

> מִנְהַג נְבִיאִים, שֶׁכָּל אֶחָד יִטּוֹל בְּיוֹם זֶה עֲרָבָה מְיֻחֶדֶת, מִלְּבַד הָעֲרָבָה שֶׁבַּלוּלָב.‏

So you shouldn't be using the same Aravot for Lulav and Hoshanoth (as the Aravot for Hoshana Rabba are customarily called.).

Furthermore I'm puzzled why you say you hold everything at the same time, as the Kitzur says one puts down the 4 Minim before taking the Hoshanoth.:

> אֵין לוֹקְחִין אוֹתָהּ עִם הַלּוּלָב בְּיַחַד, אֶלָּא כְּשֶׁמַּגִּיעִין לְתַעֲנֶה אֱמוּנִים, מַנִּיחִין אֶת הַלּוּלָב וְהָאֶתְרוֹג וְנוֹטְלִין אוֹתָהּ, לְפִי שֶׁאָז מִתְפַּלְּלִין עַל הַמָּיִם.

BTW: In the previous siman, the Kitzur recommends using fresh Aravot daily:

> וְנוֹהֲגִין לִקַח בְּחֹל הַמּוֹעֵד בְּכָל יוֹם עֲרָבָה חֲדָשָׁה לַלּוּלָב, וְהוּא הִדּוּר מִצְוָה.‏

Comment: In regards to the 4 minim and hoshanot, it's what everyone does in  my community.

Comment: That would match the Shulchan Aruch in סימן תרסד that says: יֵשׁ מִי שֶׁאוֹמֵר שֶׁאַף בְּיוֹם זֶה מַקִּיפִים בַּלּוּלָב וְלֹא בָּעֲרָבָה; וְלֹא נָהֲגוּ כֵן, אֶלָּא לְהַקִּיף בּוֹ גַּם בָּעֲרָבָה. And then again:  וְאַחַר הַנִּעְנוּעַ הָרִאשׁוֹן יָכוֹל הוּא לִטְּלָהּ עִם הַלּוּלָב, וְכָל שֶׁכֵּן בִּשְׁעַת הַקָּפָה. The Remo says: וְהַמִּנְהָג פָּשׁוּט  לִטֹּל הָעֲרָבָה עִם הַלּוּלָב בְּשַׁחֲרִית בִּשְׁעַת הַנִּעְנוּעַ וּבִשְׁעַת הַקָּפָה, עַד שְׁעַת הַחֲבָטָה וְנוֹטְלִים הָעֲרָבָה לְבַדָּהּ; וְיוֹתֵר טוֹב שֶׁלֹּא לִטְּלָהּ עִם הַלּוּלָב כְּלָל. Never seen this done...

Comment: I would "Add Another Answer" as soon as I have time,with the "other" opinion...